# Is it required to nullify ArrayList before recreating an object?

Tags: java, object, memory

I am not sure if it is going to consume more & more memory while working with the arraylist. I am confused when going through following block of code:

```
headerRow = new ArrayList<>();
headerRow.add("");
xlHeader.add(headerRow);

// headerRow = null;                     //<----- This is the line of confusion.
headerRow = new ArrayList<>();
```

Should the headerRow be nullified ?

What will happed to the Blank String Object ("") added to `headerRow` ?

Answer (score 3):

`headerRow` will have reference to newly created `ArrayList` and the old one will be registered to garbage collection.

So, nullification is not required.

Also,

```
headerRow = new ArrayList<>(); // in JDK 7
```

rather than

```
headerRow = new ArrayList();
```

is a correct syntax for instantiation.

Comment: In this particular case, it may be eligible for GC because of `xlHeader.add(headerRow);`. and xlHeader is accessible.

Answer (score 2):

**This is not required**, It will refer to the newly created object. The variable `headerRow` will refer to the newly created `ArrayList`.

So you can directly use `headerRow = new ArrayList();`

Answer (score 1):

You just use

```
headerRow = new ArrayList();
```

No need to nullify it before ,**JVM** manages it.

And in the first two lines of code

```
List<String> headerRow = new ArrayList<String>();
headerRow = new ArrayList();
```

That second line is redundant.There is no need to  write `headerRow = new ArrayList();`

Since you already initialized in the before line.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you do this:

```
List<String> headerRow = new ArrayList<String>();
// First one is correct; lose the line that follows.
headerRow = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This operation do not have any affect on performance what so ever.

We can set null to reference when we use it in form of control to not perform a action again.

For example

```
   Closable stream = getStream();

  try {
    stream.close();
    stream = null;
  catch(Exception e) {
    log(e);
  } finally {
    if(stream != null) {
      try { stream.close(); } catch(Exception empty) {}
    }
  }
```